# Getting compiler error when trying to print out contents of vector

Tags: c++, vector

Here's what I have so far:

```
 int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
    {
        srand(time(NULL));
        vector<int> deck;
        vector<bool> drawn;
        for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++)
        {
            int numvalue = rand()%20;

            if (drawn[numvalue - 1])  // this checks if their are duplicate values
            {
                i--;
                continue;
            }
            else
            {
                drawn[numvalue - 1] = true;
                //vector<int> deck;
                deck.push_back(numvalue);
            }
        }
        copy (deck.begin(), deck.end(), ostream_iterator<int>(cout, " "));
        return 0;
    }
```

the Compiler error I'm getting is:

Edit: solved the compiling issue, but now this is seg faulting...

I'd like to print out the contents inside my vector deck, and after doing some reading I thought the best option would be to use the function copy. Any ideas how I can fix this?

Comment: This is wrong on multiple levels, starting with the location of the `deck` declaration. Calling `operater[]`  using a random index on a vector of bools that has never been populated with anything is its own tragedy in the making (it invokes **undefined behavior**).

Comment: I suggest adding a breakpoint just before the `if` that attempts to check `drawn` and see what the state of drawn is.

Comment: Or use  `.at(numvalue-1)` and when it crashes you'll have a much clearer picture of *why*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Declare deck at the top of main like such, so it's not declared out of scope

```
int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
    srand(time(NULL));
    vector<int> deck;
    vector<bool> drawn(20);
    for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++)
    {
        int numvalue = rand()%20;

        if (drawn[numvalue - 1])
        {
            i--;
            continue;
        }
        else
        {
        drawn[numvalue - 1] = true;
        deck.push_back(numvalue);
        }
    }
    copy (deck.begin(), deck.end(), ostream_iterator<int>(cout, " "));
    return 0;
}
```

Also

```
int numvalue = rand()%20;
```

can easily return 0, and with if (drawn[numvalue - 1]), you're accessing drawn[-1] about 5% of the time. Much smarter to change it to:

```
int numvalue = rand()%20 +1;
```

Also as WhozCraig points out below, you never initialized drawn, which will lead to segfaults.

Answer (score 2):

Your deck is being defined in a scope that has finished by the time the copy is called.  Move the declaration of deck up further before the start of the for loop so it remains in scope.

Comment: that let me compile, but my program is segfaulting now

Comment: you'll need to resize() your drawn[] before you start accessing it